# How to change material ui MenuItem background color that there are no white "blocks" react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

So im doing a site to learn react and mui but i have no idea how to change the color of options of the  component.

```
import vector from './Vector.png';
import { Select, MenuItem, FormControl, InputLabel } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Bitcoin from "./bitcoinicon.png";


export const Navbar =()=>
{


    return (
        <div id="Navbar" >
            <div id="logo">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div id="jackpotDiv">
                    <img src={vector} style={{marginTop: "5px", float: "left"}}></img> 
                    <div id="jackText">Jackpot</div>
            </div>
            <div id="helpDiv">
                <div id="circleHelp"></div>
                <div id="helpText"> Help </div>
            </div>
            <div id="waluta" >
                <FormControl sx={{width: "200px", height:"50px"}}>
                        <InputLabel id="demo-select-label" ></InputLabel>
                        <Select labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
                                     id="demo-multiple-name" 
                                     filled
                                     style={{color: "white", backgroundColor:"#20222E", borderRadius:"8px", margin: 0}}>

                            <MenuItem value="bitcoin" style={{backgroundColor:"pink" }}>
                                <img src={Bitcoin} style={{width: "18px", height:"18px", marginRight:"18px", float: "left"}}></img> 1250
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

this is my code

i have tried to change the background color of the MenuItem inside the component but it leaves me with something like that [my effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5jiY.png). Im expecting something like this [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMTX1.png)